# How to prevent SwiftUI from adding additional hyphen characters inside text?

Tags: swiftui

I have a string with letters only such as in the example below:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("onbrtudvlxzqhjjihhxzahktdarusdyphghqonoatlmdhudyptmbjvoyxnxfwdbzpxbstvhydcbxrvygeuqnjbfawjwbbocutfilrzwninzuhrtukkuqakwrxymapyfhehxtrnvsvimuasswqzlcuvqpqwkdegaksnpxzogmkmgzxyrumstduqubxadimarhdyqhkwgaefkuordmlpltpvvcqwahjbizectvfviwpucgcekajsplitecsnoclhjnugieevhmswlfrzqctbknfpnwnguvkhuzzdahvsmhhmailrycijndfsgcwzosbors")
    }
}
```

SwiftUI displays this view like below:

[image: swiftui]

So as you can see SwiftUI adds additional hyphens on end of each line and starts new line in random places. I would like to display it as it is without any additional hyphens at the end of each line. UILabel from UIKit by default displays it like below and I would like to have a similar result in SwiftUI. Is there any way to do that in SwiftUI (without using UIKit) or at least prevent those hyphens from appearing automatically?

[image: uikit]

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to break up the string into individual characters and then put them all together again in the style of a flow layout.

- I tried the approach of using a `Canvas` for this. The canvas closure receives a `GraphicsContext` and this can be used to measure the size of `Text` items. It kind of worked, but since a `Canvas` is greedy and uses all the space available, it wasn't possible to restrict the height to the minimum necessary. Also, it didn't wrap regular words properly. So I scrapped this attempt (it can be found in the answer history, if you're interested).
- A better approach is to use a custom `Layout`. However, when the text is a regular collection of words with spaces between them, you would expect it to wrap the words normally. This means it needs to recognise words and add newlines between words if possible, but resort to newlines between letters when a word is too big for a line.

So here is an attempt to implement a custom `Layout` that works this way.

```
private struct Letter: LayoutValueKey {
    static let defaultValue = Character(" ")
}

struct LetterByLetterLayout: Layout {
    typealias Cache = LetterSizes

    struct LetterSizes {
        let letterHeight: CGFloat
        let letterWidths: [Character: CGFloat]
        let words: [String]
        let wordWidths: [CGFloat]
        var isEmpty: Bool {
            words.isEmpty
        }
    }

    func makeCache(subviews: Subviews) -> LetterSizes {
        var letterHeight = CGFloat.zero
        var letterWidths = [Character: CGFloat]()
        var words = [String]()
        var wordWidths = [CGFloat]()
        var word = ""
        var wordWidth = CGFloat.zero
        for subview in subviews {
            let char = subview[Letter.self]
            let letterWidth: CGFloat
            if let w = letterWidths[char] {
                letterWidth = w
            } else {
                let size = subview.sizeThatFits(.unspecified)
                if letterHeight == 0 {
                    letterHeight = size.height
                }
                letterWidth = size.width
                letterWidths[char] = letterWidth
            }
            if wordWidth > 0 && char == Character(" ") {
                words.append(word)
                wordWidths.append(wordWidth)
                word = String(char)
                wordWidth = letterWidth
            } else {
                word += String(char)
                wordWidth += letterWidth
            }
        }
        if wordWidth > 0 {
            words.append(word)
            wordWidths.append(wordWidth)
        }
        return LetterSizes(
            letterHeight: letterHeight,
            letterWidths: letterWidths,
            words: words,
            wordWidths: wordWidths
        )
    }

    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout LetterSizes) -> CGSize {
        var w = CGFloat.zero
        var nLines = 0
        if !cache.isEmpty, let containerWidth = proposal.width {
            let nWords = cache.words.count
            var lineWidth = CGFloat.zero
            for i in 0..<nWords {
                let word = cache.words[i]
                var wordWidth = cache.wordWidths[i]
                if lineWidth > 0 && lineWidth + wordWidth > containerWidth {

                    // Start a new line
                    nLines += 1
                    w = max(w, lineWidth)
                    lineWidth = 0
                    if let space = word.first {
                        let spaceWidth = cache.letterWidths[space] ?? 0
                        wordWidth -= spaceWidth
                    }
                }
                if wordWidth > containerWidth {

                    // Add the letters of the word one by one, skipping the
                    // leading space character if not the first line
                    var skip = nLines > 0
                    for char in word {
                        if skip {
                            skip = false
                        } else {
                            let letterWidth = cache.letterWidths[char] ?? 0
                            if lineWidth > 0 && lineWidth + letterWidth > containerWidth {
                                nLines += 1
                                w = max(w, lineWidth)
                                lineWidth = 0
                            }
                            lineWidth += letterWidth
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                    // Add the width of the full word
                    lineWidth += wordWidth
                }
            }
            if lineWidth > 0 {
                nLines += 1
                w = max(w, lineWidth)
            }
        } else {
            nLines = cache.isEmpty ? 0 : 1
            w = nLines == 0 ? 0 : cache.wordWidths.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
        }
        return CGSize(width: w, height: CGFloat(nLines) * cache.letterHeight)
    }

    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout LetterSizes) {
        let containerWidth = bounds.width + 0.0001
        var x = CGFloat.zero
        var y = bounds.minY
        var lettersAdded = 0
        let nWords = cache.words.count
        for i in 0..<nWords {
            let word = cache.words[i]
            let wordWidth = cache.wordWidths[i]
            if lettersAdded > 0 && x > 0 && x + wordWidth > containerWidth {
                x = 0
                y += cache.letterHeight
            }
            var skip = x == 0 && lettersAdded > 0
            for char in word {
                if skip {
                    skip = false
                } else {
                    let letterWidth = cache.letterWidths[char] ?? 0
                    if x > 0 && x + letterWidth > containerWidth {
                        x = 0
                        y += cache.letterHeight
                    }
                    let subview = subviews[lettersAdded]
                    subview.place(at: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX + x, y: y), proposal: .unspecified)
                    x += letterWidth
                }
                lettersAdded += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```swift
struct TestView: View {

    let longText = "onbrtudvlxzqhjjihhxzahktdarusdyphghqonoatlmdhudyptmbjvoyxnxfwdbzpxbstvhydcbxrvygeuqnjbfawjwbbocutfilrzwninzuhrtukkuqakwrxymapyfhehxtrnvsvimuasswqzlcuvqpqwkdegaksnpxzogmkmgzxyrumstduqubxadimarhdyqhkwgaefkuordmlpltpvvcqwahjbizectvfviwpucgcekajsplitecsnoclhjnugieevhmswlfrzqctbknfpnwnguvkhuzzdahvsmhhmailrycijndfsgcwzosbors"

    let loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    let theQuickBrownFox = "The quick     brown fox     jumps over     the lazy     dog"

    private func textBlock(text: String) -> some View {
        LetterByLetterLayout {
            ForEach(Array(text.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, char in
                Text(String(char))
                    .layoutValue(key: Letter.self, value: char)
            }
        }
        .background { Color.yellow }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            textBlock(text: longText)
            textBlock(text: loremIpsum)
            textBlock(text: theQuickBrownFox)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

There would be scope to improve the layout by adding more refinements, such as:

- allow line breaks where the text already contains a hyphen
- add support for multi-line text alignment.

Comment: Answer revised to use a custom Layout instead

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `Text` only hyphenates text if the text is localised. By passing a string literal, you are using the `.init(LocalizedStringKey)` initialiser. If you don't need localisation, simply use the initialiser that takes a `String` instead.

You can do this in multiple ways:

```
Text("..." as String)
// or
let text = "..."
Text(text)
```

If you do need localisation, I can't think of anything else except to add U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE between all the characters, which is admittedly rather silly.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. It still adds hyphens when I try to do it in this way. But actually this idea with zero width space works for me so while it looks a bit stupid at least it gets the job done so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding zero width space between each letter (as Sweeper mentioned in other answer) which is a bit funny workaround but at least it works. It seems that currently there is no other proper way to do this. So the workaround is:

```
extension String {
    var withZeroWidthSpaces: String {
        map({ String($0) }).joined(separator: "\u{200B}")
    }
}
```

and then

```
Text("onbrtudvlxzqhjjihhxzahktdarusdyphghqonoatlmdhudyptmbjvoyxnxfwdbzpxbstvhydcbxrvygeuqnjbfawjwbbocutfilrzwninzuhrtukkuqakwrxymapyfhehxtrnvsvimuasswqzlcuvqpqwkdegaksnpxzogmkmgzxyrumstduqubxadimarhdyqhkwgaefkuordmlpltpvvcqwahjbizectvfviwpucgcekajsplitecsnoclhjnugieevhmswlfrzqctbknfpnwnguvkhuzzdahvsmhhmailrycijndfsgcwzosbors"
    .withZeroWidthSpaces)
```